# Translation of "a simple vista"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the most idiomatic English translation of the Spanish phrase *a simple vista*? Does it mean "at first glance," or does another expression fit better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up the word *vista* in the RAE dictionary, you'll find that *a simple vista* and *a primera vista* (literally, "at first glance") are the same, and they mean the same as "at first glance".

Comment: And what about "at first sight"?

Comment: [This thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=65468) seems to say it means "to the naked eye" more than "at first glance."

Comment: @jrdioko that is because a simple vista can mean both. When "simple vista" is "vista" plus the modifier "simple", it means "to the naked eye" (like when seeing Jupiter). However, when it's the expression "a simple vista" it means "at first glance", and you can use the synonym "a primera vista" (like when having a look at something). So you see "simple" can mean "without aid" or "without detail" depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The best translation I can think of is "***to the naked eye***". It refers to something you can see without the help of auxiliary devices such as a microscope or a pair of binoculars. Of course, it can also be used metaphorically.